# Entity framework tuning

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-mapping

having a problem and hoping someone can help.

This is my real world example. I have 4 tables: 
Person
Plan
Coverage and 
CoveredMembers

Each person can have many plans, each of those plans can have many coverages. Each of those coverages can have many CoveredMembers.

I need a query that will apply a filter on Plan.PlanType == 1 and CoveredMembers.TermDate == null. This query should bring back any person who has a medical type plan that is not terminated. but i also need all the child records included. each of those persons who fit the filter with their plans, coverages and coveredmembers as well.

This SQL statement would do just that:

```
SELECT Person.*, Plans.*, Coverages.*, CoveredMembers.* 
FROM Person P 
INNER JOIN Plan PL ON P.PersonID = PL.PersonID 
INNER JOIN Coverage C on PL.PlanID = C.PlanID 
INNER JOIN CoveredMember CM on C.CoverageID = CM.CoverageID 
WHERE CM.TermDate = NULL AND PL.PlanType = 1
```

in EF (4.0 vs 2010) i have done this

```
var Q from p in context.Persons
join pp in context.Plans
on p.PersonID  equals pp.PersonD
join c in context.Coverages
on pp.PlanID equals c.PlanID 
join cm in context.CoveredMember
on c.CoverageID equals cm.CoverageID
where cm.TermDate == null && pp.PlanType = 1 && 
pp.ActiveFlag == true 
select p;
```

then

```
var people = Q.Include(people => 
people.Plans.Select(plans => plans.Coverages.Select(cc =>  cc.CoveragedMembers)))
.ToList ();
```

if i set a breakpoint on the var people = Q line and do

```
((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)Q).ToTraceString();
```

before the query is actually sent to the database with ToList() (before the include statements)
i take that query and get back the exact amount of records i should get back.

then i running a sql trace (in SQL Profiler) and let the query be sent to the database (the include statements).  i see the sql statement being sent to the database has lost all its filtering.
its basically returning the same people but the filter on the child objects is gone and 
is returning all the data for these people.  (the plan.PlanType = 1 and coveredMember.TermDate = null is missing)

maybe this is not the way to accomplish this?  anyone have any thoughts? is it even possible with EF?
this is a very simple SQL statement (albeit across 4 tables) so i dont think this should be this much of a problem, though im sure im the problem by not doing something correctly

Comment: Did you mix up `Q` and `q`, or are they different?

Comment: they are the same. that was a typo. edited it.

Comment: I know its possible to do this

    context.Persons.Include("Plans.Coverages.CoveredMembers")
    .ToList();  but i need to filter on those Properties in the include

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the placement of the `Include`. It is more or less common to put `Include`s directly behind the entity they apply to. I'll show you what I mean and at the same time rewrite your query using the navigation properties:

```
var q = from p in context.Persons
                         .Include(people => people.Plans
                         .Select(plans => plans.Coverages
                         .Select(cc =>  cc.CoveragedMembers)))
        from pp in p.Plans
        from c in pp.Coverages
        from cm in c.CoveragedMembers
        where cm.TermDate == null && pp.PlanType = 1 && pp.ActiveFlag
        select p;
```

(Using navigation properties does not change anything essentially, but it makes life much easier). I've seen includes placed at the end of a linq statement been interpreted as outer joins but the same includes right at the beginning to inner joins.

I might add that you do not need the `Include`s at all if it is possible to decide beforehand which data you need, and project (`select`) those into a (named or anonymous) type, i.e. something like

```
select new { Person = p, Plan = pp, CoveredMember = cm }
```

in stead of `select p`. Better still, pick out specific properties:

```
select new { Person = p.Name, Plan = pp.Plan, CoveredMember = cm.Name }
```

and you will greatly reduce the amount of data you fetch. `Includes` have a way of blowing up the query result both in width and in length.

Comment: this is fine accept anonymous properties are read only.  which means you cant do anything with it accept read it, which doesnt help too much.

Comment: Is it possible to re-think when you need an entity versus an anonymous type (eg. I use this approach frequently for search results, etc - and then load the entities when I want to modify one or use it specifically)? There are also cases where you simply must work outside of EF (i.e. running stored procs if doing code / database first). I am wondering if some of the struggle you are having now couldn't be resolved by a pivot in how you are thinking about using your entities. Running through your design and approach with a third party might help.

Comment: @DexterMorgan You can also create named types, say `select new PersonDto { Person = p.Name, .... }`. But I'm curious, does the first query now include the filters?

Comment: @Matthew i appreciate the advice but we get a file on a weekly basis to update people and info. this file contains 16K people.  and even if only 25% have a data change thatis 4K trips to the db.  i'd rather just get them all back at once and have them writable.  also, maybe its just me but i really dont see the point of having the overhead of EF if you are just going to call stored procs.  the extra overhead should leviate the need to write sprocs.  just my opinion.

Comment: The overhead is there to abstract the DAO layer activity you used to have to do and provide a bit of a paradigm shift in how you now can treat your objects as entities without as much concern about persistence. There are still things (and bulk reads/writes are one of them) where you may need to step outside EF (IMHO). If you think about it though, you would likely be handling something like this in a slightly different manner no matter what your data layer looked like. Also - even all 16k records, reading from the file and loading the data will be your bottleneck on that process, not your DB.

Comment: That is to say - I think you might be trying the address a problem you might not have. (Caveat - you obviously know a lot more about your system, but my expertise comes from spending countless hours trying to cleverly solve problems I don't end up having anyway :)

Comment: the current system we have doesnt really have any problems that need to be solved other than maintenance.  if we need to add a column to the db then we have to update sprocs and Data access layer to accomondate reads and saves. this is why were thinking about going to EF so we didnt have worry about things like anymore.  i was under the impression (and maybe incorrectly) that you could just udpate your enitites, call savechanges() and wham its good.  if any table column is added you just refresh your entities.

Comment: i know there is more to than EF than that but if it cant even do that i dont see the point of moving away from what we have now.  i dont see the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You `cannot use filtering with Eager loading (Include)`.

So You can do something like below (this is a sample code)

```
public Company Get(int id)
{
    var query = from c in
                    (from co in db.Companies
                        where co.Id == id
                        select new
                        {
                            Company = co,
                            CompanyPerson = from person in co.Persons
                                            where person.IsActive && !person.IsDeleted
                                            select person
                        })
                select c;

    //Create my company object
    Company company = new Company();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        company = item.Company;

        //Add persons to my company object
        foreach (var companyPerson in item.CompanyPerson)
        {
            company.Persons.Add(companyPerson);
        }
    }
    return company;
}
```

For more information check this post [**Eager Loading (include) with filter in Entity Framework**](http://dotnethill.com/post/2011/07/12/Eager-Loading-%28include%29-with-filter-in-Entity-Framework.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: doesnt accomplish what i want. i only went 2 levels deep (Person and Plans) just to make it simple.  the sql created is a left outer join and returns all Persons regardless if they have PlanType = 1 or not. grant it only plan type 1 is in the plan list the persons who have the plan. but if i have 500,000K persons in my database 
and only 25K have plantype 1, then it is bringing back 475K records it doesnt need to.

Comment: it seems this left outer join is by design?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c00d47b8-c686-4e9f-825c-d4ffb78ee7bd/

if that is the case then EF is retarded.  this shoudl be a simple query. maybe my expectations of EF were too high but this seems like something really simple to do and if it cant do it then in my opinion it is completely USELESS.  im surprised that the developers who created this haven thought of a way to do this.

Comment: @DexterMorgan Yes actually provided link by you gave lot of information about this situation.Any way which EF version Are you using ?

Comment: i installed and referenced 4.1 but it says 4.0 in visual studio still

Comment: @DexterMorgan Now MS has released EF 6 Alpha 2.If you're running Vs 2012 then do try to accomplish what you tried with ef 4.1.B'cos  sometimes they have given that feature(may be) .Check this link for more details about latest version http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/11/entity-framework-6-alpha2-now-available.aspx

Comment: @DexterMorgan No problem.Still you can use EF 6.You may loose some Async features which ships with latest Ef. But all other performance wise improved features can use with vs 2010.So try that.

Comment: no luck. still creating the same garbage sql query.  probably time to throw this on the trash heap since it cant do something as simple as this

Comment: @DexterMorgan Mmm.. OK. Then you can try this with combination of Ef and SP for your scenario.What do you think about that?

Comment: why would i want to use stored procedures. defeats the purpose of what EF is supposed to do if you ask me

Comment: @DexterMorgan You know there are lot we can get from ef as a ORM tool.But sometimes we unable to take everything.B'cos ef is still in early stage of development.But after ms did open source of ef now it's going relay well for all departments (performance , efficiency and lot more).So we can predict your kind of issues will quickly sort it out may be ef 7.So until then we have to adapt or bypass some scenarios to tame this animal.One option is using SP for such kind of scenarios. EF 6 is giving full support for sp development.I feel you must think about that before get rid of this ORM.

Comment: sorry dont see the point of creating sprocs and having to maintain them. if im going to do that i might as well keep the same platform i have now with a DAL and sprocs.  if EF7 does what i need it to then ill think about changing.  im not going to "adapt" way from what is working to something that doesnt work. thank you for all your help though